# Button retains focus when mousedown and mouseout, accesibility implications

Tags: focus, accessibility

It seems to be a consistent browser behaviour that when the user drags out of a `a` element, to avoiding clicking on releasing the mouse button, that that element retains focus until the user clicks somewhere else.

[image: Demonstration of previous paragragh]

Is there an accessibility related reason for this?

It seems to be a common user behaviour (interaction) to negate a click 'halfway through' and, in MacOS, at least, is the default menubar mouse behaviour.

I guess I'm looking for a way to force a drop of focus on mouseout but I don't know whether this is bad for accessibility.

Incidentally this is visually bad ugly either `button` is used as a UI object or an `a` is styled as a button.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the focus remains on the button/link or if you force it away will not cause an accessibility issue with regards to WCAG conformance.  It does not fail any guidelines.

It comes close to failing [WCAG 3.2.2 On Focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#on-focus) but I think the timing of your events technically makes it pass.  The mousedown event causes the focus event and you are not doing anything with the focus event.  It's when the mouseup event happens that you're trying to move focus so in theory, you are not changing the context on the focus event.

I'm not sure that means you should do what you have proposed from a UX perspective but there probably aren't a lot of people that rely on the default behavior.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the mouse down initiates focus, the mouseup whilst over the target triggers the action and a mouse away from the target cancels the action but leaves focus with the target. It is unclear to me the reasoning behind this.

Comment: I was just pointing out that if you had to find a WCAG requirement that caused the current behavior to fail conformancy, it would be 3.2.2.  But technically that requirement isn't failing because the change of context would happen on a mouseup and not an onfocus.